# Jquery to swap img src with a string? + url encoding

Tags: jquery, image, src, url-encoding

I am working with a qr code generator and I need the image (the generate qr code) to swap out when the user hits the 'generate code' button.  So I need the image src to become both the textarea value and the error correction value combined, as well as url encoded.

Here is what I have:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $qr_image = $('#qr-image');
    var $qr_text = $('#qr-text');
    var $qr_elc = $('#qr-elc');

    $.qrGenerate = function() {
        $qr_image.attr('src', '$qr_text.val' + '$qr_elc.val');
    }
    });
</script>
```

the line below is where my troubles come from.  Right now when I click the button I get: "http://urlblahblah/$qr_text.val$qr_elc.val"

`$qr_image.attr('src', '$qr_text.val' + '$qr_elc.val');`

I also know the encoding is done by using escape('');, but I am not sure where to put this.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you put quotes around a variable it becomes a string, you should use variable name without quotation marks:

```
$.qrGenerate = function() {
    $qr_image.attr('src', $qr_text.val() + $qr_elc.val());
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Both of you were right, I chose who answered first for the correct one. :)  It works, I appreciate it.  Funny how one little mark can ruin everything.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using quotation-marks around your values you are combining two strings `$qr_text.val` and `$qr_elc.val()`, thus your result. Get rid of the `'` around your values and you should be fine:

```
$qr_image.attr('src', $qr_text.val() + $qr_elc.val());
```